# axios request token returns null when refreshing page

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, use-effect

```
"axios": "^0.20.0",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

i am using **axios** and i'm sending a request in **useeffect** and it works but when i **refresh** the page (F5) the **token** that i fetch from redux and add it into axios instance is **null**

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    const token = store.getState().auth.token;
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    // Do something before request is sent
    console.log("req config", config);
    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

this is just a api call and in refresh my token is **'Bearer null'** :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getAssessments();
    getGroups();
    getAssessmentUsers();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Just make sure to have the token first before calling anything. In other words, you need to get token first, then check token in other api calling.

Comment: i have it in redux store, but how can i be sure to have it before sending request ? is there any way to wait for the token or ... ?

Comment: Pass the `token` as a dependency in the useEffect hook and when you have the token perform the request

Comment: Yes, the simpliest way is check the token before set Authorization header :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the token to be `rehydrated` in you redux store after the refresh, it doesn't happen immediately. If this still doesn't work you need to verify that the token is persisted with `redux-persist`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (token) {
    getAssessments();
    getGroups();
    getAssessmentUsers();
  }
}, [token]);
```

This useEffect hook will be triggered when the `token` has changed, eg: prevToken !== token, so you also need to add the if-statement to perform the requests when the token is not null